# jQuery plugin problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problems with making my webpage responsive. I am using a plugin called `jquery-momentum-scroll`. But when I give specific height for a specific resolution (using @media), it does not instantly respond to my given resolution.

For example, if I resize my browser window, it shows the previous given responsive resolution that I set for different resolution. But, after a refresh on the browser, it takes the given property and works fine. After, including the plugin this problem occurred.

I have tried this in all other browsers it gives same result.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Take a look at this: [mcve]

Comment: I think you are missing an `onresize` event in your code. Sharing a fiddle of your work would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with! `!important`?
You can override the height by using `!important`. Just try it,  I hope it will be OK.